# Migrate From Google Java API Datastore to Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, migration, datastore

I have an entire app running on GAE and its datastore... now I need to migrate the application and its datastore to mysql db.

What is the best approach for acchieving this, is there an bulkdownloader if I used the Java API.

It's been 4 days trying to look for this answer, thank you very much in advaced.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [approcket](https://github.com/k7d/approcket/) for that. It's a tool you can use to sync your GAE Datastore with a MySQL database.

It's [well documented](https://github.com/k7d/approcket/wiki) but not massively active. I've used it before, and it does the job well.

Comment: Tks did not know about this API.